# Find closest time in inner join Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, one with crypto values in USD pulled at different interval (every 30 mn approx).

'crypto' table

```
   +-----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
    | id  | date_hour           | crypto_code | crypto_name | price_usd |
    +-----+---------------------+-------------+-------------+-----------+
    |  13 | 2018-05-24 16:43:29 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7553.75   |
    |  14 | 2018-05-24 16:43:29 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 584.764   |
    |  15 | 2018-05-24 16:43:29 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.617043  |
    |  16 | 2018-05-24 16:43:29 | DCR         | Decred      | 102.578   |
    |  17 | 2018-05-24 16:43:29 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.0164824 |
    |  18 | 2018-05-24 16:43:29 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 289.619   |
    |  19 | 2018-05-24 17:00:01 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7528.51   |
    |  20 | 2018-05-24 17:00:01 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 584.769   |
    |  21 | 2018-05-24 17:00:01 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.614629  |
    |  22 | 2018-05-24 17:00:01 | DCR         | Decred      | 102.229   |
    |  23 | 2018-05-24 17:00:01 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.016547  |
    |  24 | 2018-05-24 17:00:01 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 286.252   |
    |  25 | 2018-05-24 17:31:01 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7508.15   |
    |  26 | 2018-05-24 17:31:01 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 584.024   |
    |  27 | 2018-05-24 17:31:01 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.607491  |
    |  28 | 2018-05-24 17:31:01 | DCR         | Decred      | 101.801   |
    |  29 | 2018-05-24 17:31:01 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.0163432 |
    |  30 | 2018-05-24 17:31:01 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 289.187   |
    |  31 | 2018-05-24 18:00:01 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7545.02   |
    |  32 | 2018-05-24 18:00:01 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 587.121   |
    |  33 | 2018-05-24 18:00:01 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.612734  |
    |  34 | 2018-05-24 18:00:01 | DCR         | Decred      | 102.667   |
    |  35 | 2018-05-24 18:00:01 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.0165401 |
    |  36 | 2018-05-24 18:00:01 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 289.686   |
    |  37 | 2018-05-24 18:31:01 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7574.54   |
    |  38 | 2018-05-24 18:31:01 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 590.538   |
    |  39 | 2018-05-24 18:31:01 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.620313  |
    |  40 | 2018-05-24 18:31:01 | DCR         | Decred      | 103.306   |
    |  41 | 2018-05-24 18:31:01 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.0164874 |
    |  42 | 2018-05-24 18:31:01 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 291.421   |
    |  43 | 2018-05-24 19:00:02 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7600.11   |
    |  44 | 2018-05-24 19:00:02 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 594.962   |
    |  45 | 2018-05-24 19:00:02 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.622085  |
    |  46 | 2018-05-24 19:00:02 | DCR         | Decred      | 103.229   |
    |  47 | 2018-05-24 19:00:02 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.0166324 |
    |  48 | 2018-05-24 19:00:02 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 296.651   |
    |  49 | 2018-05-24 19:31:01 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7599.6    |
    |  50 | 2018-05-24 19:31:01 | ETH         | Ethereum    | 593.13    |
    |  51 | 2018-05-24 19:31:01 | BTM         | Bytom       | 0.620733  |
    |  52 | 2018-05-24 19:31:01 | DCR         | Decred      | 101.368   |
    |  53 | 2018-05-24 19:31:01 | SC          | Siacoin     | 0.0165951 |
    |  54 | 2018-05-24 19:31:01 | ZEC         | Zcash       | 292.538   |
    |  55 | 2018-05-24 20:00:01 | BTC         | Bitcoin     | 7603.72   |
```

And another one which monitors a few wallets every X minutes called 'production'

```
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------------+
| id  | currency | date_hour           | bal_conf     |
+-----+----------+---------------------+--------------+
|   1 | CMM      | 2018-05-25 08:00:00 | 24.87        |
| 197 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 10:56:53 | 0.82431267   |
| 198 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 10:56:54 | 0.77711006   |
| 199 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 10:58:02 | 81.33782690  |
| 201 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 11:00:23 | 0.77711006   |
| 202 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 11:30:15 | 0.83045272   |
| 203 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 11:30:16 | 0.77711006   |
| 204 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 12:00:23 | 0.83441691   |
| 205 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 12:00:23 | 0.77711006   |
| 206 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 12:30:18 | 0.84046355   |
| 207 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 12:30:31 | 0.77711006   |
| 208 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 13:00:14 | 0.84323421   |
| 209 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 13:00:18 | 0.77711006   |
| 211 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 13:30:18 | 0.77711006   |
| 212 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 13:58:05 | 85.18699829  |
| 213 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 14:00:01 | 85.18699829  |
| 215 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 14:00:19 | 0.77711006   |
| 216 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 14:02:02 | 85.18699829  |
| 217 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 14:02:45 | 0.85096095   |
| 218 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 14:02:54 | 0.77711006   |
| 219 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 14:03:32 | 0.85096095   |
| 220 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 14:03:36 | 0.77711006   |
| 221 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 14:04:01 | 85.18699829  |
| 222 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 14:06:01 | 85.41043305  |
| 223 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 14:09:55 | 0.85096095   |
| 224 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 14:10:17 | 0.77711006   |
| 225 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 14:30:01 | 85.75066324  |
| 226 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 14:30:10 | 0.85363614   |
| 227 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 14:30:13 | 0.77711006   |
| 228 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 15:00:01 | 86.67740965  |
| 229 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 15:00:12 | 0.85694953   |
| 230 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 15:00:14 | 0.77711006   |
| 231 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 15:30:01 | 87.02525693  |
| 233 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 15:30:18 | 0.77711006   |
| 234 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 15:34:33 | 0.86264950   |
| 235 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 15:34:40 | 0.77711006   |
| 236 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 15:38:30 | 0.86264950   |
| 237 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 15:38:31 | 0.77711006   |
| 239 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 15:40:15 | 0.77711006   |
| 240 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 15:44:01 | 87.49497772  |
| 241 | BTC      | 2018-05-24 15:48:37 | 0.03155398   |
| 243 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 15:50:20 | 0.77711006   |
| 244 | BTC      | 2018-05-24 15:51:22 | 0.03155398   |
| 245 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 15:55:01 | 87.67270990  |
| 246 | BTC      | 2018-05-24 15:57:01 | 0.03155398   |
| 247 | BTC      | 2018-05-24 16:00:02 | 0.03155398   |
| 248 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 16:00:01 | 87.67270990  |
| 250 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 16:00:21 | 0.77711006   |
| 251 | ETH      | 2018-05-24 16:10:15 | 0.86810400   |
| 252 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 16:10:19 | 0.77711006   |
| 253 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 16:11:01 | 88.15004778  |
| 254 | BTC      | 2018-05-24 16:19:01 | 0.03155398   |
| 256 | SIA      | 2018-05-24 16:20:19 | 0.77711006   |
| 257 | BTM      | 2018-05-24 16:22:01 | 88.15004778  |
```

I need to find for every date_hour in the production table the closest value of price_usd (closest in term of timing) to the corresponding crypto_code (production.currency=crypto.currency)

I tried this code:

```
SELECT t.date_hour,t.currency,t.bal_conf, s.price_usd
FROM production t
INNER JOIN crypto s
 ON(t.date_hour like s.date_hour and s.crypto_code=t.currency)
```

But it does not return all the production records, I therefore need that in case there is not an exact matching date in the crypto table, to find the closest one.

Comment: ORDER BY ABS(x-y)

Comment: When you say you haven't found a solution, do you mean that you haven't found one at all? or you haven't found a performant solution. The easeist way is to do a cross join

Comment: Thanks, I have added my current query to explain my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that with a subquery, that get the `price_usd` from `crypto` where the currency codes match and the [absolute value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) of the [difference of the time stamps](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) equals the minimum of the difference of the time stamps for the currency code. We get that minimum in another subquery.

```
SELECT p.date_hour,
       p.currency,
       p.bal_conf,
       (SELECT c.price_usd
               FROM crypto c
               WHERE c.crypto_code = p.currency
                     AND (SELECT min(abs(timestampdiff(second, ci.date_hour, p.date_hour)))
                                 FROM crypto ci
                                 WHERE ci.crypto_code = p.currency)
                         = abs(timestampdiff(second, c.date_hour, p.date_hour))
               ORDER BY c.date_hour DESC
               LIMIT 1) price_usd
       FROM production p;
```

The `ORDER BY c.date_hour DESC LIMIT 1` just handles the rare event when two or more time stamps from `crypto` produce the same difference for the given time stamp from production. In such a case the most recent time stamp is used.

Indexes to support this query could be

```
CREATE INDEX crypto_crypto_code_date_hour
             ON crypto
                (crypto_code,
                 date_hour);
```

for the innermost subquery and

```
CREATE INDEX crypto_crypto_code_date_hour_price_usd
             ON crypto
                (crypto_code,
                 date_hour,
                 price_usd);
```

for the outermost subquery. (And none for the outer query, as there are no conditions for `production`.)

Comment: that's genius! congrats your query works perfectly. great help!